# How can I change the case of the text using vim?

Tags: vim, case

```
$ cat keys
1 auto
2 break
3 case
4 char
5 const
6 continue
$
```

Using vim, what is the quickest way to toggle the case of all the text to get this?

```
1 AUTO
2 BREAK
3 CASE
4 CHAR
5 CONST
6 CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the quickest, but what I would do is type this:

```
gggUG
```

See

```
:help gU
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
SHIFT + V
SHIFT + G
SHIFT + ~
```

Note: Text will be converted to UPPER case if **all** chars are in lower case.